# How to bind an object inside the list collection of the command object in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My command object have a list of objects. I want to bind a text field to the attribute of the object inside that list. Is it possible to do in Spring MVC?

Command object class

```
public class SubDevisonDto {

private String devId;
private List subDevisions;
```

Subdevision object class mentioned in the list

```
public class SubDivison implements Serializable{

private String subDivisonName;
private String createdBy;
private String createdDate;
private String developerID;
private List users;
```

I want text box to set the value for subDivisonName field.

I have written the Spring MVC tags like this.

```
<spring:bind path="subdivisondto.subDevisions[0].subDivisonName">
    <span class="formw">
        <input name="subDivisonName" type="text" style="width:350px;" />
    </span>
</spring:bind>
```

Just for test purpose I have given it as 0. If it's working I can make it to a variable. my requirement is, I should let the user to dynamically add subdevision objects. So, initially when page is loading I will just show one text box. I will give a button for him to add if he want to add more. I will dynamically generate text boxes when he clicks the add button. After that I have to submit the form with the list.

This jsp code gives me an error. It says:

> org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException

Is there anyway for me to do this in jsp code?

Comment: http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/11/30/spring-forms-dynamic-lists-and-ajax/

Comment: This link seems like useful. I'll have a look on it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. But, it's not the solution for my requirement as I need to implement a dynamic list. but I found a solution for this question.

As I understood, first time we have to send data from back end to bind input elements. I didn't find a way to bind form elements which takes input without sending a list data from beck end. But when we send data and bind the elements, we can take input from those elements. So, I think to bind the element in a situation like this we need to send data first time. Correct me if this statement is wrong. Because, that would be a more good solution for me.

We need to use the lazy list and jsp code is bit modified.

Your command class object should be created as below mentioned.

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.list.LazyList;
import org.apache.commons.collections.FactoryUtils;



public class SubDevisonDto {

    private String devId;

    private List subDevisions = 
        LazyList.decorate(
          new ArrayList(),
          FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(SubDivison.class));
```

JSP code should look like below.

```
<c:forEach items="${subs.subDevisions}" var="obj" varStatus="gridRow">
```

Binding an input element text box

```
<spring:bind path="subdivisondto.subDevisions[${gridRow.index}].subDivisonName">
      <span class="formw"><input name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" type="text"  style="width:350px;" />
```

binding an input element check box. This input element makes a list.

```
<spring:bind path="subs.subDevisions[${gridRow.index}].users">
              <c:forEach items="${obj.users}" var="dependenttwo" varStatus="dependentRowtwo">
                <li>
                  <input name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>" type="checkbox" class="users" value="<c:out value="${dependenttwo}"/>"/>
                  <c:out value="${dependenttwo}"/>
                </li>
                </c:forEach>
                </spring:bind>

`subs` is a map key name. the value for this key `subs` is a list of my DTO objects which named as `SubDevisonDto `
```

This code works fine for me.

Thanks the support given.

Answer (score 1):

In dto :

```
private List<SubDivision> SubDivisions =  new AutoPopulatingList<SubDivision>(new SubDivisionFactory());
```

and factory would be something like:

```
public class SubDivisionFactory implements AutoPopulatingList.ElementFactory<SubDivision> {

    public String createElement(int index) {
        SubDivision subDivision = new SubDivision();
        return subDivision;
    }
}
```

using [AutopopulatingList](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/AutoPopulatingList.html) from spring. And your jsp will look the same, you can iterate over as many as you want.

Comment: I'm working with spring 1.2.x. AutopopulatingList is not there for this version. So, seems like I can't use this solution. Thanks a lot for your support. Appreciate it. I tried with LazyList and doing some modifications in JSP as well. But it didn't work yet. Same error comes. Thank you.

Comment: @Nazneeen, you'll have to implement your own - or upgrade.

Comment: yes. It seems like hard to do with this. Thanks a lot for the support. I'll try to find something.

Comment: I found the answer for my question. But, it's not the solution for my requirement as I need to implement a dynamic list. but I found a solution for this question.