# How to bind list (in list) binding to Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, collections, bind

I have 3 model classes for binding.

```
    class FormBean {
          private String a;
          private List<A> aList;

      //.. get/set

   }


class A {
   private String aname;
   List<B> bList;

   // get/set

}

class B {
   private String name;
   private String id;
   // get/set
    ..
}
```

And Here is my Controller

```
public ModelAndView controlMethod (@ModelAttribute FormBean param) {

       ...
}
```

==============

And the client-side,

The codes that I made like this.

```
<form id="userInsert" name="userInsert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <input type="text" name="aList[0].bList[0].name" value="aaa"/>
    <input type="text" name="aList[0].bList[1].name" value="aaa1"/>
    <input type="text" name="aList[0].bList[2].name" value="aaa2"/>


    <input type="text" name="aList[1].bList[0].name" value="aaa3"/>

</form>
```

===============

But

It's not working well.

But when I request like this.

```
<input type="text" name="aList[0].aname" value="aaa"/>
```

then , it's working well..

I want to know what is problem.. and What should I do?

Or It can bind or not.

Regards.

Comment: take a look at [Dynamic form and data binding with Spring MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23294897/1066779)

Comment: @Rembo yeah, I saw that already. but my problem is the class Form can be List type. Means the List<FormBean> a can have List<A> ...

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8270501/1066779) is what you looking for